# Can we create custom APDU for non-smart (memory type) contactless card?

Tags: authentication, access-control, smartcard

I want to implement card-based authentication for the parking system in a university. Currently all students own a Java Card-based student ID card, if they have not broken or lost it.

Can we create custom APDU structures in a blank, non-smart 13.56Mhz card?

I'll elaborate.

While the majority of the parking lot is occupied by students, a handful of the school staff also park in this lot. The staff do not have a card similar to the student ID card. I also want to take account of students who lost the student ID card. To make use of the student ID card and also serve people without one, I need to find a drop-in replacement for the student ID card.

The parking auth system communicates with the student card using APDU commands, that is, a command that selects an applet and provides additional parameters. The card answers the APDU command with certain static data unique to each student. That's it for the card. Therefore this is entirely a read-only operation as far as the card goes.

From what I understand, the Java Card is a microprocessor card (a smartcard), while the usual, lower cost blank card that we can find easily on the market is a memory card. For a drop-in replacement with limited functionality I should use the memory card.

I wish to emulate the APDU structures of the Java Card in the blank card, the drop-in replacement. In short, I want the drop-in replacement to give the same answer as the original student ID card's answer when queried by the reader, and only for a few types of APDU commands (i.e from a single Java Card applet).

Is this possible? I have read that most chips like a Mifare Classic/Ultra Light or an NXP chip are using proprietary, pre-programmed APDU commands. I don't think I need to use a new real smartcard just to emulate a few APDU applets that answer with specific data.

The standards being used are ISO 14443-A and ISO 7816-4.